# Avoid distortion and wrong scaling of shapes and objects when printing Excel worksheets

Tags: excel, image, pdf, printing, size

Excel distorts shapes ans objects when printing.

A spreadsheet with several objects (Active-X-Radio Buttons and other) and programatically created shapes (Lines, arrows and rectangles as seen above the word 'System') should be printed as such:
[image: correct PDF-File]

Sometimes however, assumingly when the memory is low, excel distorts the layer holding all graphical objects. 
In the printout these objects are completely out of size:
[image]

The bug occurs randomly and independent of the way, the sheet is printed. Either programatically saved as PDF or manually printed using the print dialog.

Comment: A post by 
MADMush in a [related discussion forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/08fa689a-6e8e-4850-99e4-f1600e385522/excel-distorts-image-when-printing?forum=excel) suggests, that the **zoom level of the active window** is responsible for this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, unbelievable, the zoom level of the active window is responsible for this behaviour.
Put Zoom of the excel page at 100% and the pictures are wrong and distorted. Put 99% and it's perfect. It sounds crazy but it works.

Comment: Thank You Louis. You Say, that setting the window zoom level to 99 % bevore printing solves the problem? Whow, I have to test this and will report back...